# reindex cataloginventory_stock via api

Tags: magento-1.7, api, stock, indexer

We currently are using the api to update inventory via a vb.net service which works but appears that until we update the 'Stock Status' index manually the updated status doesn't show properly for products that had been changed.

Is there a way to change stock status index via the api?  Looks like we have to do something with cataloginventory_stock (code 8).

Here is my current code on how I update a product.

```
Dim myStock As New catalogInventoryStockItemUpdateEntity
myStock.qty = 10
myStock.is_in_stock = 1
myStock.is_in_stockSpecified = True
myStock.manage_stock = 1
myStock.manage_stockSpecified = True
Dim iRetVal As Integer = ws.catalogInventoryStockItemUpdate(sessionId, sMagentoSku, myStock)
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot start the indexer via the API.